# turn on and off bluetooth periodically

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an app that looks at the paired devices of a phone.

I have it so that the bluetooth turns on. But when I put in the wait it chrashes every time I open it.

How would I have it so that it turns on for a minute every 5 minutes or something like that. And only turns off if it hasn't connected to anything.

Any help would be great.
Thanks

**code**

```
private void turnOnBt() {
    //Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    //startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable();  
    try {
        wait(15000);
        notify();
        BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().disable();
        wait(60000);
        notify();
        //BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth restarted", 0).show();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**paired code**

```
private void getPairedDevices() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    devicesArray = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(devicesArray.size()>0){
        for(BluetoothDevice device:devicesArray){
            pairedDevices.add(device.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
02-21 13:10:18.559: D/TextLayoutCache(25101): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
02-21 13:10:18.589: D/libEGL(25101): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
02-21 13:10:18.609: D/libEGL(25101): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-21 13:10:18.639: D/libEGL(25101): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-21 13:10:18.639: D/libEGL(25101): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
02-21 13:10:19.329: D/OpenGLRenderer(25101): Enabling debug mode 0
02-21 13:13:07.819: D/TextLayoutCache(25306): Using debug level: 0 - Debug Enabled: 0
02-21 13:13:07.839: D/libEGL(25306): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
02-21 13:13:07.849: D/libEGL(25306): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-21 13:13:07.869: D/libEGL(25306): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-21 13:13:07.869: D/libEGL(25306): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
02-21 13:13:07.969: D/OpenGLRenderer(25306): Enabling debug mode 0
02-21 13:16:42.419: D/AndroidRuntime(25750): Shutting down VM
02-21 13:16:42.419: W/dalvikvm(25750): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Test.bluetooth/com.Test.bluetooth.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1967)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at com.Test.bluetooth.MainActivity.turnOnBt(MainActivity.java:92)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at com.Test.bluetooth.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:76)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1931)
02-21 13:16:42.439: E/AndroidRuntime(25750):    ... 11 more
```

**Second Logcat**

```
02-21 13:47:30.079: D/AndroidRuntime(27230): Shutting down VM
02-21 13:47:30.079: W/dalvikvm(27230): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.bluetooth.device.action.FOUND flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.Test.bluetooth.MainActivity$3@2be07420
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:737)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at com.Test.bluetooth.MainActivity$3.onReceive(MainActivity.java:137)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
02-21 13:47:30.089: E/AndroidRuntime(27230):    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Post your logcat error.

Also, why would you turn the entire adapter off after you look at the paired devices...Remember the calls to .enable() and .disable() are to be done after a user interface response!

Never programatically without any user input! What if I have another device connected, like a headset for example? See more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#enable%28%29).

I understand that if the adapter is not enabled you cannot get the paired devices, but still!

Comment: I'll post them when I get back to my laptop. I want it to turn off if there is no paired devices available and to check again in 5 minutes. I'm doing it with user input as I don't need it asking every time.

Comment: Ok, so I've seen the problems with the wait, I've added `notify()` to the code and now it doesn't crash. but it never turns off the bluetooth now.

Comment: @ELSheepO Ok, now post the new error. Also, a simple change: make an object called BluetoothAdapter myAdapter = getDefault....bla bla. Check to see if it's not null and then use it in your code from then on. Second thing, register a receiver for the hardware events. Like BT TURNING OFF, TURNING ON, ETC. And check you get those. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED

Comment: @ELSheepO Why are you still trying to reset the adapter? Do you understand you are breaking coding rules and also your users will get a weird and hacked user experience?!?

Comment: Added second log. I'm resetting it so that it doesn't drain the battery while the app is running. But bluetooth is needed so that the app can switch from walk to car mode, if that makes sence.

Comment: @ELSheepO Having the adapter on does NOT drain your battery! So that excuse is invalid! Have you done the tests behind your claim? I have and it does not make sense. GPS drains it, BT not so much, 5% per day...

Comment: @ELSheepO It seems you search for BT devices every time, instead of going through the already paired devices list. That is why you need the BT adapter enabled...So you always look for a carkit or something...It's not your device probably, otherwise you could connect to it and then on disconnect you would know user left the car....Still please leave the BT adapter alone...

Comment: @ELSheepO So the bug is on the onReceive method of your activity. It happens when you receive an Intent with DEVICE FOUND.

Comment: I'm searching for paired devices, I'll put the code in the question. What would the best way to connect to a car kit, do they have a certain address?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24905/discussion-between-radu-and-elsheepo)

Answer (score 1):

In your `MainActivitiy::turnOnBt()` method - this is where there the exception is thrown you have a call to `Thread.wait();` (presumbly on line 92)

I'm not quite sure what you try to achieve with this as a call to `wait()` on the UI thread will (I'm pretty sure) crash your app with an [ANR Exception](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

To call `Thread.wait();` you have to do it in a synchronized block:

```
synchronized(this) {
    try {
        Thread.wait();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

But as I said - this is **not what you want**. Have you mixed up `Thread.wait()` with `Thread.sleep(...);`? Event then, calling `Thread.sleep(...)` on the UI Thread is [really not recommended](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html).

Comment: I'm trying to make it wait before it turns off the bluetooth. Line 92 is where i have the `wait(15000)`. If i sync the method it should work is what your saying?